# Install external file from subdirectory (relative path) using Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I would like to install an external file.

My installer is located in

```
c:\somedir\setup.exe
```

And the external file is located in

```
c:\somedir\download\MyApp.exe
```

My code to do that is

```
[Files]
Source:"\download\MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}";Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist
```

For some reason, Inno Setup does not seem to find this file.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems:

- The path `\download\MyApp.exe` relative to `c:\somedir\` resolves to `c:\download\MyApp.exe`, as the leading `\` goes back to the root folder. You would need to use `download\MyApp.exe`.
- The Inno Setup does not resolve external file paths relatively to the installer anyway. You have to use a full path, see the documentation for the [`Source` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=Source):

  > **When the flag `external` is specified, `Source` must be the full pathname** of an existing file (or wildcard) on the distribution media or the user's system (e.g. "{src}\license.ini").

  You can use the [`{src}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=src) to get a full path to the installer folder.

---

```
[Files]
Source: "{src}\download\MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist
```

Comment: Good job! `Flags: external` helped!

Answer (score 1):

Use the {src} constant:

```
[Files]
Source:"{src}\download\MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}";Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist
```